# Use the rows of two data frames as input for function, saving output as new data frame.

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames, with identical number of columns but differing number of rows. I want to apply a function which outputs a value. The function uses one row of df1 against one row of df2 and outputs a single numerical value. I want to apply this function for every combination of rows possible between the two data frames and save the output as a new data frame.

Can someone help me with this? Right now I'm doing it manually and it would take a very long time.

Comment: Would do you post the code of your datasets please ? best regards

Comment: Please post a few rows of `df1` and `df2`, your function and how you want your output to look like...

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without more data, but you might want to look into `expand.grid()`. This function gives you a data.frame containing one row for each combination of a list of vectors.

Comment: don't you think it'd be better if you had this as a comment? After all, it's just suggesting a function. I think content and length of this makes it a valid comment, but not an answer. Cheers.